Quartz scheduler performance tuning/overhead
I am new to Quartz Scheduler Framework. We are using quartz 2.3.2 for scheduling jobs. I have around million scheduled jobs, which has different frequencies. But mostly I get 6000-7000 triggers every minute. These jobs are very light on computation side, they just publish message over rabbit. I am using postgres database to persist these jobs. I have a cluster of scheduler service instances to handle the scale.
I have all schedules as crontriggers with misfire policy as "MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_IGNORE_MISFIRE_POLICY".
Quartz configuration:


 spring:
  application:
    name: my-scheduler-service
  quartz:
    job-store-type: jdbc
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: never # Let Flyway handle initialization
    properties.org.quartz:
      scheduler:
        batchTriggerAcquisitionMaxCount: 600
        instanceName: JobScheduler
        instanceId: AUTO
      threadPool:
        class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
        threadCount: 600 # Todo: determine appropriate size here
        threadPriority: 5
      jobStore:
        maxMisfiresToHandleAtATime: 400
        acquireTriggersWithinLock: true
        isClustered: true
        driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
  resources:
    global:
      enabled: true
      url:
      hikari:
        poolName: GlobalDBPool
        minimumIdle: 20
        maximumPoolSize: 50



Problems

We have deployed the service on Kubernetes with 4 pods. Unfortunately, we are seeing huge delay in task executing. Resulting in huge number of misfires. We are not able to catchup to this misfires and live jobs are not getting triggered.
We also observed that quartz locking was taking time (70-74 sec's). Mostly this is for "SELECT * FROM QRTZ_LOCKS WHERE SCHED_NAME = ? AND LOCK_NAME = $1 FOR UPDATE" query.

What are the things I can do to improve the quartz performance?

Are these tasks executed concurrently? If it is executed concurrently and each task execution needs to establish a connection with the database, according to your description, “But mostly I get 6000-7000 triggers every minute”， I suggest increasing the number of connections configured in the database connection pool.Your   maximumPoolSize has only been set to 50.

Additionally, you may need to ensure that each task can be completed within its execution cycle under normal circumstances, otherwise the misfire policy you have set to "MISFIRE-INTRUCTION-IGNORE-MISIFIRE-POLICY" will lead to an increasing backlog of tasks.
